# how to create window.location response in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, response

For creating a `.zip` file for checked items with selectbox, i need a response back from the php that leads to the path the `.zip` file is stored.

This is my ajax call:

//  AJAX for Checkbox download

```
$(document).on('click' , '.cb_down' , function() {      
    var checkboxes_down = [];               
    $('.rafcheckbox').each(function() {   
        if(this.checked) {              
             checkboxes_down.push($(this).val());                                
        }  
    });  
    checkboxes_down = checkboxes_down.toString(); 

   $.ajax({  
        url:"",                                 
        method:"POST",                  
        data:{ checkboxes_down:checkboxes_down },  
        success:function(response){
            window.location = response; // this should lead me to the zip file
        }
        //.........
```

My php:

```
// Multiple download (checkboxes)
if(isset($_POST["checkboxes_down"])) { 

   // create a tmp folder for the zip file
   $tmpfolder = $MainFolderName.'/tmpzip';
   if (!is_dir($tmpfolder)) {
     mkdir($tmpfolder, 0755, true);
   }

   $checkboxfiles = explode("," , $_POST["checkboxes_down"]); 
   $filename = "archive.zip";
   $filepath = $tmpfolder."/";

   foreach($checkboxfiles as $checkboxfile) {               
     Zip($checkboxfile, $tmpfolder."/archive.zip"); // Zip is a function that creates the .zip file
   }   

   // header come here

   echo $filepath . $filename; // the path to the .zip file

   exit;
```

The `.zip` file is successful created. I checked it.
The problem is: i do not get the response back from the php script. 
So i can not download the .zip file.
What i am doing wrong?

**!** I changed the echo to `'zip file is created'` but even that echo i do not receive as response back

Comment: You should send response in json from server side.

Comment: "i do not get the response back from the php script" — The only thing I can think of which would cause that behaviour is if you did something (e.g. submit a form) which causes the browser to navigate away from the page with the JavaScript in it before the response got back from the server. There isn't enough code in your question to determine if that is happening though.

Comment: Also check "console.log(response)" in client side.

Comment: Use chrome Inspector->Network to find out what your php script is actually doing. Add some more echo's in there as well just to debug.

Comment: @Amos: i made an echo: `'zip file is created` in the php and even that echo i do not receive as response!

Comment: "even that echo i do not receive as response" — What are you doing to determine this?

Comment: Can you add "Zip()" method/function code with your question?

Comment: @Quentin in my php: `echo 'zip file is created'` and in my success function: `$('.echo').html(response);` . The div with class `echo` should contain the echo but it is not there

Comment: @Amit  `.zip` is successful created. that is not the problem.

Comment: @mudraya —You should follow the advice you were given earlier — "Use chrome Inspector->Network to find out what your php script is actually doing." — look at the details of the request and the response.

Comment: first of all, comment out your ZIP() call and add an echo in that for loop to print out the file details. lets start there and let us know what you get